# Do situations exist for using the reduce() Method to create an array to store name:value pairs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

My request is for assistance in using arr as a function argument in the JavaScript Array reduce() Method.

After reading, the reduce () method is for accumulating a total for array; and the reduce() method exist to accumulate (or total) array values into a single value.

I am seeking to comprehend the purpose for creating an array of values that satisfy a specific condition as detailed in its block code.

The reduce() Method syntax is

array.reduce(function(total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr), initialValue) 
where currentIndex and arr is optional.

I saw the following example.

```
var issues = [
    {
       comments_count: 5,
       id: 144948778,
    },
    {
    comments_count: 1,
    id: 14383618,
    }]

var lonelyComments = issues.reduce(function(arr, issue){
    if (issue.comments_count == 1){
       arr.push(issue);
    } 
    return arr
}, [] );
```

The answer is: comments_count: 1, id: 14383618

Instead of the above, my choice would be to use the filter() Method.

Comment: I didn't get what your problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, what you are looking for but there are use cases to apply these helper methods (`reduce/filter/map`). As you said, you will prefer `filter` for this particular scenario, which is perfect choice.

```
var lonelyComments = issues.filter(function(issue) {
    return (issue.comments_count === 1)
}, []);
```

`reduce` is for reducing the `array` into something else based on all the items. Suppose you have an `2D array` and want to create an object from it. Then you can use `reduce` in this case like following.

```
var array = [['name', 'john'], ['age', '23']];

var obj = array.reduce(function(accumulator, item) {
  accumulator[item[0]] = item[1];
  return accumulator;
}, {});
```

Above is just a simple use case and there are much more complex use cases where `reduce` can save your day.

Comment: Good Day @Vipin Kumar!

Thank you for your answer.

I would appreciate your providing information on using the reduce method to take advantage of obtaining results in more complex solutions.

I want to expand beyond only applying reduce() in situations where it would return a total.